# Is my DTD correct and how do I check it?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, dtd

This is my very first attempt at writing a DTD from scratch and I seem to be having trouble. When I checked it in www.xmlvalidation.com, it tells me I have an error but I don't seem to see the problem.
Here is my xml code taken from sample given by lecturer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE studentMarks SYSTEM "marks.dtd">
<studentMarks>
<matricNO>S123</matricNO>
<courseCode>CYY505</courseCode>
<mark>70</mark>
<matricNO>S123</matricNO>
<courseCode>CYY502</courseCode>
<mark>84</mark>
<matricNO>S123</matricNO>
<courseCode>CYY503</courseCode>
<mark>72</mark>
<matricNO>S123</matricNO>
<courseCode>CYY501</courseCode>
<mark>90</mark>
<matricNO>S123</matricNO>
<courseCode>CYY506</courseCode>
<mark>87</mark>
</studentMarks>
```

and this is my DTD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!ELEMENT studentMarks (matricNO,courseCode,mark)>
<!ELEMENT matricNO (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT courseCode (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT mark (#PCDATA)>
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you :)

Comment: What's the error message you got?

Comment: @Oscar I got this error message.The content of element type "studentMarks" must match "(matricNO,courseCode,mark)"

Comment: By the way, I don't think this is a good XML design. The data will be much easier to process if you add a wrapper element around each group of three child elements.

Comment: @MichaelKay i agree. But such was the sample given to me so yeah.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration

```
<!ELEMENT studentMarks (matricNO,courseCode,mark)>
```

means that studentMarks must have exactly three element children, with the specified names. If you want this group of three elements to repeat, use

```
<!ELEMENT studentMarks (matricNO,courseCode,mark)*>
```

(And next time you ask a question on StackOverflow, please don't say that you got an error without telling us what the error was).